# Oracle TIMESTAMP Comparison with TO_TIMESTAMP function

Tags: oracle

I am having a problem getting the result I expect from an Oracle query.

The `TO_TIMESTAMP` I am using appears to work fine:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('11-16-2014 00:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL
```

Returns
    2014-11-16 00:00:00

My table `AUDIT` has a column `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` of Oracle type `TIMESTAMP(6)`.  I don't know if it helps but this column also has these attributes:

- `DATATYPE=93`
- `COLUMN_SIZE=11`
- `DECIMAL_DIGITS=6`
- `NUM_PREC_RADIX=10`
- `CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH=11`

Lets look at the table size:
    `SELECT count(*) FROM RPT.AUDIT`
returns
    `623981`

This table grows about 500 rows a day.  So **I would expect this query to return a number under 1000**.
Instead I get the whole table:
    `SELECT count(*) FROM RPT.AUDIT WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > TO_TIMESTAMP('11-16-2014 00:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`
returns
    `623981`

Thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the name of an Oracle function the database prefers to use the function instead of your column - and thus, since `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (the function) is always greater than a time in the past the predicate returns TRUE for every row in the table, and thus every row gets counted. If you put a table alias in your query and qualify the column name with the alias you should get what you expected:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM RPT.AUDIT a
  WHERE a.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > TO_TIMESTAMP('11-16-2014 00:00:00', 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Or you can just refer to the column as `RPT.AUDIT.CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` if you like.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I am not a DBA and would never have guessed that someone long ago would allow an Oracle keyword into our table schema.  Good grief.  Thank you!